# How to pull out values with a symbol next to them (e.g. *)

Tags: excel

I have created a bivariate correlation matrix that correlates a bunch of psych scales. I am looking to quickly show which scales showed significant correlation between each other. As I've exported from SPSS, entries that are significant have * or ** next to them, indicating p<0.05 or p<0.01.

Is there a way to quickly pull out all significant Pearson's corr values, and their associated column/row section names?

Comment: It might be easier to help if you provide sample data and the desired result (in text form, not image pls)

Answer (score 0):

You could try some advanced filtering (see here https://trumpexcel.com/excel-advanced-filter/)

Alternatively you could write formulae like this (in this example the data is in A1:C3):

```
 =IFERROR(IF(FIND(CHAR(42),A1:C3),A1:C3&" Row "&ROW(A1:C3)&" Col "&COLUMN(A1:C3)),"")
```